# azure data factory copy activity timeout

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm using a copy activity inside a foreach loop in order to download images from links provided from a lookup. the pipeline works as expected mais sometimes the copy activity fails.

pipeline :

[image]

the error :

[image]

by the way I'm using  self-hosted integration runtime, any help please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check Timeout of Copy Data Activity. Try to **increase Timeout** of Copy Data Activity. By default it is 7 days.

Also Try to increase the Retry Count. By default it is zero.

[image]

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-troubleshooting#troubleshoot-copy-activity-on-self-hosted-ir